# PHP: number_format rounding

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding

Hi I've been having a problem rounding numbers to **-0** instead of just a **0**

code:

```
<?php
$num= 0.000000031;

$round = number_format((float)$num, 1, '.', '');

echo $round * -1;
?>
```

output:
**-0**

expected output:
**0**

I've been looking to any solution but nothing found.

kindly explain & help me why it rounds up to **-0** instead of **0**? thank you

Comment: 1. `$xx` is i think `$num` 2. Why do you multiple `* -1` ?

Comment: @Riad updated sorry typo

Comment: @Rizier123 I have a big list of numbers with decimal places to multiply it to -1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the rounding makes it -0.

The $round variable contains this before the last line:

```
string(3) "0.0"
```

You can verify this with adding this line:

```
var_dump($round);
```

before the echo.

So if you multiply "0.0" (string) with -1 then the result will be "-0"

Because (string)0 is casted to (float)0 before the multiplication and

```
(float)0 * -1 = -0

php5 -r 'var_dump((float)0*-1);'
float(-0)
```

Which is completely normal based on the floating numbers behaviour. (More details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero )

If this is a problem you can add 0 to avoid this "magic":

```
php5 -r 'var_dump((float)0*-1+0);'
float(0)
```

Comment: Very good explanation! (Signed zero didn't know that!) Also take a look here: http://3v4l.org/kANUX (interesting which php version do different things)

Comment: good way & it make a common sense **0 + -0 = 0** which is a simple way to make it positive and never think of it. thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

You PHP code  it's disorganized.

I assume the var $xx on the second line it's $num.

Then, you must first do all operations (operation layer) and then do presentations (presentation layer):

```
<?php
    // Operation layer
    $num = 0.000000031;
    $round = $num * -1;

    // Presentation layer
    echo number_format($round, 1, '.', '');
```

When you do a number_format retrieve a string, not a number.

Comment: The question is why it rounds up to `-0`

Comment: same thing if you try your code it outputs **-0.0**.

Answer (score 0):

Since [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) returns string, you need to cast it to get expected result.

```
<?php

$num= 0.000000031;

$round = number_format((float)$num, 1, '.', '');

echo (int)$round * (-1);  //print 0 

?>
```

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f31c5c539d14c2fa2947fb46a6bfe2340b87e2cd)

Comment: But this also gives `-0`: `echo (float)0.0 * -1;` why?